# VB.NET - where column_name and column_name2 between column_name2 (date) and column_name2 (date)

Tags: vb.net-2010

So, I tried to get the UID.Text and try to show timein.
I want try to do this where `uid.text = uid timein >= yyyy-MM-dd and timein <= yyyy-MM-dd`
See the Image below, so that you'll see the code and error.

[image: code]

[image: error]

```
MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MySqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost; uid=xx; pwd=xx; database=studentdatabase; Convert Zero Datetime=True;"
    Dim Adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim BSource As New BindingSource
    Dim DT As New DataTable
Try
    MySqlConn.Open()
    Dim Query As String
    Query = "Select TimeIN, TimeOUT from tbl_time where UID =" & TextBox_UID.Text & " between TimeIn = '" & DateTimePicker2.Text & "' And TimeIn ='" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "'"
    MSCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
    Adapter.SelectCommand = MSCommand
    Adapter.Fill(DT)
    BSource.DataSource = (DT)
    DataGridView_Search.DataSource = BSource
    Adapter.Update(DT)
    MySqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
     MySqlConn.Dispose()
End Try
```

Comment: Post code here (indented with 4 spaces) - don't use images because it's harder for us to copy and test.

Comment: Uh, sorry. Just new here and just a starting at programming. Please do reply, thanks a lot! God Bless~

Comment: It looks like your `between` syntax is incorrect - it should be [expression BETWEEN value1 AND value2](http://www.techonthenet.com/mariadb/between.php) (e.g. `TimeIn BETWEEN val1 AND val2`)

Comment: Uh, how do I explain this, I want to do is, Get the UID.Text I'am using 2 database-tables. If I get the UID.Text then find the date range in TimeIN.

    `select * from tbl_time where uid=uid and between timein >= date and timein <= date`

there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct SQL syntax for your query would be this:

```
select * from tbl_time where uid=uid and timein between date1 and date2
```

Try using this code instead:

```
Query = "Select TimeIN, TimeOUT from tbl_time where UID =" & TextBox_UID.Text & " TimeIn between '" & DateTimePicker2.Text & "' And '" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "'"
```

Comment: Oh there. Thank you! It works now. I mean it. Thank you! This code is for my thesis. =')
`Query = "Select TimeIN, TimeOUT from tbl_time where UID =" & TextBox_UID.Text & " and TimeIn between '" & DateTimePicker2.Text & "' And '" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "'"`